# How to hide navigation bar in image view and appear it again in tableview?? As both are in same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, viewcontroller

I am having `UIview` over a container which holds `UITableviewcontroller`, i given segue to my view controller from navigation controller. Now i would like to run my `UIView` with navigation bar hidden. I tried with code but it is in vain either both views having navigation bar or both does not have.

I am working with storyboard.

Code:

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 480)];
    animationImageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"], nil];
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 2.2f;
    animationImageView.animationRepeatCount=1;
    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];

}
```

I use this code:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

but it hides in both my animated view and in my `tableViewController`.

Can anyone help me??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you `setNavigationBarHidden:NO` when you return back to your table view?

Comment: yes i tried it.. but it won't work..

Comment: have u tried bringSubviewtofront, maybe your view lies behind and is not visible??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805962/how-to-identify-whether-the-given-animation-completed-or-still-in-process

Check the above link for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES // In UIView(previous VC)
```

and

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO // In TableView
```

Comment: You can make this in Attribute inspector in one VC hidden in two not hidden

Comment: yes of course i done.. but changes remains the same.