# How to identify animations completed or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7, uiimage

I am trying to find out whether my animation runs and completed or else it is still in process??

```
animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 480)];
animationImageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"], nil];
animationImageView.animationDuration = 2.2f;
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount=1;
[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];
```

Can anyone help me?

I am having `UIview` over a container which holds `UITableviewcontroller`, i given segue to my view controller from navigation controller. Now i would like to run my `UIView` with navigation bar hidden. I tried with code but it is in vain either both views having navigation bar or both does not have.

I am working with storyboard.

Actually am using `UIImageView` for "Splashscreen" purpose.

Comment: simply writing your problem ,please try to paste some code or what you had done to achive it

Comment: Your question is too vague. There are lots of different kinds of animations. Are you doing UIView animation? CAAnimation? What kind specifically? What do you need to do when the animation completes? Both UIView animation and CAAnimation have mechanisms that will run your code when the animation completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.2f animations:^{

    UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 480)];
    animationImageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg2"], nil];
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 2.2f;
    animationImageView.animationRepeatCount=1;
    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Finished");
}];
```

To find out animating or not

```
    if ([YourAnimationImageView isAnimating]) {

        NSLog(@"Yes animation in progress");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"NO. animation has been stopped/finished");
    }
```